# Open terminal from gVim

Tags: c++, vim, terminal

I was wondering if there is a way to compile a c++ file in gVim and then to run it by pressing a button and to open a terminal with the corresponding cpp .out file.

Now I have this 2 lines in my .vimrc for compiling and runing:

```
map <F5> :<C-U>!g++ -O2 -DLOCAL -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-result -static %:r.cpp -o %:r<CR>
map <F9> :<C-U>!./%:r<CR>
```

But when I press F9 it runs my script inside of gVim, I want it to be opened on the linux terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change

```
map <F9> :<C-U>!./%:r<CR>
```

to

```
map <F9> :<C-U>!x-terminal-emulator -e ./%:r -hold<CR>
```

In fact, you can use any of your favorite terminal. Just check how to pass in commands to the terminal. In most of the cases, it is `-e`.

`-hold` is to hold the terminal from vanishing.

To get more insight, read [How can I make a script that opens terminal windows and executes commands in them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46627/how-can-i-make-a-script-that-opens-terminal-windows-and-executes-commands-in-the)

Comment: It works but when I run my file and I enter the input after pressing "ENTER" it close the terminal and I can't see de output, what could be the issue?

Comment: Sorry for replying late. If the issue is still not resolved, then follow the suggestion. Did you add -hold option or anything related to that operation?

Answer (score 3):

Your mappings look like to be 20ish years old. You probably don't want the mappings to work from visual mode. They are better restricted to normal mode, be nore-mappings, and also, vim has been integrating compilation from the start (unlike vi), see `:h quickfix`.

Expecting you have a proper version of gnumake installed (all Linux systems, and not mingw), you can simply work with

```
" I wouldn't let no-unused-result out, nor use -static... but this is your choice
:let $CXXFLAGS = '-O2 -DLOCAL -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-result -static'
" You also have $CFLAGS for C, $FFLAGS for Fortran (IIRC)...,
" and $LDFLAGS and $LDLIBS for libraries.

nnoremap <silent> <F5> :<c-u>make %<<cr>

" Also, you can use vim integrated terminal now
" or any other terminal, see vikram's answer
nnoremap <silent> <F9> :<c-u>vert term ./%<<cr>
```